# Run a statement if any of these variables is empty

Tags: php

So I have this:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$purpose = $_POST['purpose'];
$special = $_POST['special'];
$length = $_POST['length'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

I want to run a statement if any of these variables is empty. I know I can run an if statement checking if any of them are empty but is there a simpler way or perhaps a function that could do it with less code?

I could do this:

```
if($title == '' || $keywords == '' || etc etc...
```

But is there a method to do  it with less code? That just seems a bit clunky.

Thanks!

Comment: You can simply do `if (!empty($_POST)){}`

Answer (score 2):

For fix it i usually use this solution.

```
$keys = array('title','keywords','any_other_key');
$isError = false;
$data = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$key]) || $_POST[$key] == '') { 
        $isError = $key;
        break;
    } else {
        $data[$key] = strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
    }
}

if ($isError !== false) {
    // Error. Some fields are not filled!
    // Error field are in $isError variable;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `!isset($_POST[$key])`

Answer (score 1):

```
$vars=array('title','keywords','purpose','special','length','email');

$allfilled=true;
foreach ($vars as $var) {
  $$var=$_POST[$var];
  if ($$var == '') $allfilled=false;
}

if (!$allfilled) ...
```